How to create animated gradients in React Native?
I'm trying to create an animated gradient for my expo app. I know this can be done for websites using pure CSS:
.container {
background: linear-gradient(45deg, "red", "green", "blue", "yellow")
animation: color 12s ease-in-out infinite
}

But I'm not able to figure out how to do it in React Native. I was originally using expo-linear-gradient for rendering the Linear gradient but apparently that package can't be used for creating animations so I switched to React Native Skia (with Reanimated). I tried for many hours but I still wasn't able to get that effect. And I'm not able to find anything online.
Can someone give a hint on how this could be achieved.

Animations are the one thing react-native differs greatly from react in. I recommend using react-native-reanimated for animations. Going with react native skia for animating gradients seemed to be the right move. I tried to use reanimated's createAnimatedComponent for expo-linear-gradient and couldn't get to work, so I went with react native skia. Most Skia components accepts SharedValues so the animating them is just doing reanimated stuff to your values:
import {
  colorManipulators,
} from "@phantom-factotum/colorutils";
import {
  Canvas,
  LinearGradient,
  Rect,
  vec
} from '@shopify/react-native-skia';
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { LayoutRectangle, StyleSheet, View, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';
import { interpolateColor, useDerivedValue, useSharedValue, withRepeat, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';

type Props = {
  contentContainerStyle?: ViewStyle;
  children: ReactNode;
  colors: string[];
  start:[number,number]
  end:[number,number]
  // style?:ViewStyle;
};

export default function AnimatedGradient({
  contentContainerStyle,
  children,
  colors,
  start,
  end
}: Props) {
  // store children layout properties
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState<LayoutRectangle>({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const animValue = useSharedValue(0)
  const darkColors = useMemo(()=>colors.map(color=>colorManipulators.blend(color,'black',0.5)),[colors])
  const animatedColors = useDerivedValue(()=>{
    return colors.map((color,i)=>interpolateColor(animValue.value,[0,1],[color,darkColors[i]]))
  })
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    animValue.value = withRepeat(
      withTiming(1,{duration:500}),
      -1,
      true
    )
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas
        style={{
          // Canvas can only have skia elements within it
          // so position it absolutely and place non-skia elements
          // on top of it
          position: 'absolute',
          width:layout.width,
          height:layout.height
        }}>
          <Rect x={0} y={0} width={layout.width} height={layout.height} strokeWidth={1}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={animatedColors}
              origin={vec(layout.width/2, layout.height/2)}
              start={vec(layout.width*start[0],layout.height*start[1])}
              end={vec(layout.width*end[0],layout.height*end[1])}
              />
          </Rect>
      </Canvas>
      <View
        style={styles.contentContainer}
        onLayout={(e) => setLayout(e.nativeEvent.layout)}>
        {children}
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});


